# Table rows in table rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is a part of my current table:

[image]

This is a table which displays the tasks completed, the duration of the task and department worked in at that time (Which means that one entry consists of *Verrichtete Arbeit*, *Zeit* and *Abteilung* and they are connected). These entries are in weekday rows (Mo. Di. Mi.) I want to add new entries for the rows of each weekday to this table now. The problem occurs when there is a td with too much text, which results in using 2 lines for one entry (e.g. entry in *Verrichtete Arbeit* on Monday and entry in *Abteilung* on Monday). The fact that 2 lines are used, is not the problem. But when there is a new entry, the new value of *Zeit* would be placed directly under the last value and it would look like this:

[image]

Here is a picture, edited in gimp which shall display how it should look like:

[image]

This is the HTML setup which I use for this purpose:

```
<table id="report_table">
  <tr id="tr_table_header">
    <th id="th_week_day"></th>
    <th id="th_completed_task">Verrichtete Arbeit</th>
    <th id="th_hours_worked">Zeit</th>
    <th id="th_working_department">Abteilung</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableRowDay">
    <td class="weekDay">Mo.</td>
    <td class="completedTask">fooo foo foo ofoo foo ofoo ofoofooofff Foo foo foo foo fooo foo foooooooooooo fooooo fooo foo fooo foooo fooo</td>
    <td class="hoursWorked">2</td>
    <td class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="weekDay">Di.</td>
    <td class="completedTask">Bar</td>
    <td class="hoursWorked">4</td>
    <td class="workingDepartment">Technik</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="weekDay">Mi.</td>
    <td class="completedTask">Baz</td>
    <td class="hoursWorked">5</td>
    <td class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="weekDay">Do.</td>
    <td class="completedTask">Lorem</td>
    <td class="hoursWorked">3</td>
    <td class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="weekDay">Fr.</td>
    <td class="completedTask">Ipsum</td>
    <td class="hoursWorked">5</td>
    <td class="workingDepartment">Technik</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="weekDay">Sa.</td>
    <td class="completedTask"></td>
    <td class="hoursWorked">5</td>
    <td class="workingDepartment">Technik</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is my current CSS:

```
#a4 {
    background-color: white;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
}

table#report_table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 180mm;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 0.6mm solid black;
}

#tr_table_header {
    height: 5mm;
    max-height: 5mm;
}

#th_week_day {
    width: 5mm;
    max-width: 5mm;
}

#th_hours_worked {
    width: 10mm;
    max-width: 10mm;
}

#th_working_department {
    width: 35mm;
    max-width: 35mm;
}

.weekDay {
    width: 10mm;
    max-width: 10mm;
    height: 25mm;
    max-height: 25mm;
    text-align: center;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}

.completedTask {
    height: 25mm;
    max-height: 25mm;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.hoursWorked {
    width: 10mm;
    max-width: 10mm;
    height: 25mm;
    max-height: 25mm;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.workingDepartment {
    width: 15mm;
    max-width: 15mm;
    height: 25mm;
    max-height: 25mm;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The fixed values (mm, cm) are on purpose because the website shall be printed later on! I thought about using a table inside the row of the weekday but screwed my whole design up with this, which is unfortunate. I prefer not to use javascript but only css and html if possible. Every suggestion or help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry English is not my native language but I will edit and try to make it clearer

Comment: Have you tried using more table rows within the "Verrichtete" and "Zeit" Column? 

Like so

http://i.imgur.com/JPTDqBC.png

Comment: If I understand fine your problem, you can't achieve only with css+html. It's because you can't know how many lines are in another cell and play with it. You can write some javascript that can read line by line and calculate how many pixels fit the text, to separate the values in `Zeit` column according with that cell. I don't know if I explain fine but in resume, impossible to achieve css only. You can write separate rows without borders to simulate the same behaviour.

Comment: @Robert2 Is it possible to have a tr in a td?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi No.  Not directly, but you can have a table in a TD, however it won't be related to the table in another TD (i.e. the rows could have different heights).

Comment: When generating the table, do you know how many entries there will be for each day? For example, in picture 3, Monday has 3 entries - is this known during HTML code generation?

Comment: @Paddy I tried using a table but the table would just display in the td of *Verrichtete Arbeit* :/ It looks like [this](http://imgur.com/avlPSyV)

Comment: @S.B. no this is completely flexible. It is unknown how many entries there will be and how many lines they will use. The size of the table still has to be fixed though and the entries are connected and shall be displayed like that

Comment: @IbrahimApachi yes, but at some point you have to fill the HTML template with your actual content. at this point you should know how many entries you have, right? Because if you have this information, you can use `rowspan` to fix the layout the way you want.

Comment: @S.B. I read about rowspan already but the way it is currently setup, I use one row for one weekday, and in this table row I just have 3 td's which represent *Verrichtete Arbeit*, *Zeit* and *Abteilung* what means that I can't use `rowspan` in this case. With the current setup I would have multiple entries in one td which cause the currently unwanted layout of the entries being displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do like this, sample of a table-in-a-table structure, and no script.

*Note, I just added one weekday, though it shows the concept, and you'll have to add your own borders, etc.*

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 0.6mm solid black;
}

#th_week_day,
.weekDay {
  width: 40px;
}

.tr-inner th,
.tr-inner td {
  width: 20%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.tr-inner th:first-child,
.tr-inner td:first-child {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table id="report_table">
  <tr id="tr_table_header">
    <th id="th_week_day"></th>
    <th>
      <table>
        <tr class="tr-inner">
          <th id="th_completed_task">Verrichtete Arbeit</th>
          <th id="th_hours_worked">Zeit</th>
          <th id="th_working_department">Abteilung</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableRowDay">
    <td class="weekDay">Mo.</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr class="tr-inner">
          <td class="completedTask">fooo</td>
          <td class="hoursWorked">2</td>
          <td class="workingDepartment">Forschung</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-inner">
          <td class="completedTask">fooo foo foo ofoo foo ofoo ofoofooofff Foo foo foo foo fooo foo foooooooooooo fooooo fooo foo fooo foooo fooo</td>
          <td class="hoursWorked">4</td>
          <td class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr-inner">
          <td class="completedTask">fooo foo foo ofoo foo ofoo </td>
          <td class="hoursWorked">2</td>
          <td class="workingDepartment">Entwicklung</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```